# alguien sabe porque no imprime el json

Tags: php, json

```
$from 
$to = 20;
$query = "SELECT idempleados,nombre,apellidos FROM empleados LIMIT ?,?";
$result = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$result->bind_
param('ii', $from, $to);
$result->execute();
/* bind result variables */
$result->bind_result($idempleados,$nombre,$apellidos);
/* fetch values */
while ($result->fetch()){
    $empleados[] = array(
        'idempleados' => $idempleados,
        'nombre' => $nombre,
        'apellidos' => $apellidos
    );
}
echo json_encode($empleados);
/* close statement */
$result->close();
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Este código no imprime el json.
[image: no imprime json]

Pero cuando le doy un index al arreglo $empleados si me imprime el index que le doy. por ejemplo le doy el index 0 ysi lo imprime.

```
...

echo json_encode($empleados[0]);

/* close statement */
   ...
```

[image: impresión json index 0]

**EDIT**

Si hago print_r($empleados) recibo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya quedo solucionado
gracias a todos los que respondieron me ayudo la respuesta de @sioesi

así quedo el código

```
while ($result->fetch())
    {
    $empleados[] = array(
    'idempleados' => $idempleados,
        'nombre' => utf8_encode($nombre),
        'apellidos' => utf8_encode($apellidos)
    );
    }
  echo json_encode($empleados,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

[image: código impreso]

Comment: Si haces un `print_r($empleados)` que te arroja?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema son los caracteres... si te fijas en el elemento de tu `arreglo[7]` y `arreglo[11]` los apellidos tienen una Ñ. Por eso no funciona, debes asegurarte que tienen `UTF-8` en la base de datos. En la base de datos debe estar mal guardado.

```
while ($result->fetch()){
    $empleados[] = array(
        'idempleados' => $idempleados,
        'nombre' => utf8_encode($nombre),
        'apellidos' => utf8_encode($apellidos)
    );
}
echo json_encode($empleados, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**EDIT**

En la documentación de PHP hay un ejemplo y puedes leer más sobre esto

[PHP JSON_ENCODE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#example-4366)

Como comentas tu base de datos esta configurada con `InnoDB` y `utf8_general_ci`, por lo tanto el error esta desde el archivo en que guardas los valores... Debes configurarlo tambien con `UTF-8`

Comment: ¿Dónde ves el valor del arreglo[7]?

Comment: En la imagen que el OP subio recien como respuesta, ya que no tiene suficiente reputación para comentar.

Comment: Mi ordenador va con muuuuucho retraso. Acabo de ver la respuesta :S

Comment: si tienes razón @sioesi, quise imprimir el index 7 y no me deja, pero donde te que módificar en la DB?? si  no es mucha molestia jeje

Comment: Como tienes configurada tu base de datos que tipo de motor y que tipo de cotejo? @danieldelriocruz

Comment: motor es InnoDB y el cotejamiento: utf8_general_ci

Comment: @danieldelriocruz te deje un edit

Comment: Tu base de datos esta bien configurada, sin embargo tu archivo php que se encarga de guardar los datos debe estar malo... Si utilizas SublimeText hazle un Save with Encoding y UTF-8

Comment: es la primera vez que uso este foro jeje, pero ya lo intente con el parametro JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, y tampoco me funcionó

Comment: @danieldelriocruz Como te comente, tu bd esta bien configurada, prueba configurando bien el archivo.php que se encarga de guardar en la base de datos agregando otro usuario con un acento o una ñ y llama al indice de ese usuario en tu array.

Comment: @danieldelriocruz actualice mi respuesta!

Comment: si gracias por tu tiempo @sioesi, me ayudastee mucho :D

Comment: @danieldelriocruz Saludos y exito con el proyecto!

Answer (score 0):

Es porque tu arreglo resultante lo ingresas a un objeto, así al momento de iterarlos sería $empleados[0]...$empleados[1]... etc.
Si solo va ser un registro el que vas a ingresar en lugar de meterlo como arreglo, ingrésalo directamente.

```
    $empleados = [
        'idempleados' => $idempleados,
        'nombre' => $nombre,
        'apellidos' => $apellido
        ];
```

Si quieres imprimir con `echo` todo tu objeto puedes recorrerlo en un búcle o bien ingresarlo directamente.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

**edición**: vi que usas mysqli y mi solución se orientaba a PDO.

Comment: Eso no deberia influir en su error

Comment: ya lo intente, pero solo me guarda el último registro de mi consulta

Comment: Listo, le agregué unos cambios, mira el búcle y luego imprímelo

Comment: mira me sale este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/jqWidgetEjemplos/ejemplo3/data.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/jqWidgetEjemplos/ejemplo3/data.php on line 31

Comment: prueba así...
$result = $mysqli->get_result();
$empleados= $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: gracias @Ed García ya lo solucione